# How to detect if incoming call is full-screen or popup

Tags: android, phone-state-listener, incoming-call

I have issue, where I have PhoneStateListener what basically listens if there is phonecall. However I need to understand, if the incoming phonecall is going to be shown as full-screen up or popup (when u are using mobile while call comes in).

Is it even possible to detect and if yes, any ideas how to archieve that? I do not have any example code to show sadly, because I am simply thinking how to get that boolean and I don't know from where to even start with.

Any help is appreciated!